# How to make deck.js presentations go forward when clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery, deck.js

How do I configure deck.js so it goes to the next slide when I click anywhere on the page? Very much like Powerpoint or Impress does it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The quickest way without using the navigation module:

```
$(function() {
   $.deck('getContainer').click(function() {
      $.deck('next');
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What I used in the end and was the solution which required the least thinking effort:

Including the `deck.navigation` extension and applying the `deck-next-link` class to my `deck-container` (`<body>`)